# Multiple counts from same table which share the same day of the week

Tags: sql

I have a table which has the following:

An ID - recid e.g. 123456
A resolved date - ResolvedDateTime e.g. 02/28/2014 12:00 AM (in UTC)
A created date - CreatedDateTime e.g. 02/28/2014 12:00 AM in UTC)

I'm trying to determine, by the day of the week, how many are created and resolved on that day.

For example, the date range may be let's say 02/24/2014 to 02/28/2014. The type of data I'd like to see is:

```
  ===================================================
  ||    DayOfWeek || CreatedCount || ResolvedCount ||
  ||          Mon || 51           || 12            ||
  ||          Tue || 61           || 32            ||
  ||          Wed || 53           || 90            ||
  ||          Thu || 23           || 40            || 
  ===================================================
```

So far I have the following which brings me back the day of the week and the created count. This was reverse engineered from something that existed previously:

```
/* Declare and set the browser timezone difference since we are manually setting a date */
declare @offset int; 
set @offset = (@BrowserTimezoneOffSet);

/* This will return by the day of the week */
SELECT left(DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime)), 3) as createddatetime
       ,count(recid) as createdc
FROM Incident
WHERE DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime) >= @st_datein
AND DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime) <= @en_datein
GROUP BY 
  left(DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime)), 3)
  ,left(DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime)), 3)
ORDER BY
  left(DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime)), 3)
```

Any tips on how to get this query to start pulling back the resolved count would be great. Thanks a lot in advance - happy to answer any questions or provide more information where necessary.

Update:
Still had absolutely no luck on this.
Any one out there?

Comment: Storing timestamps in UTC is great... but, essentially, this gives different results depending on where the browser says it's from?  This seems like it's ripe for confusion: if all timestamps are coerced to the nearest start-of-day (UTC) then you and I may have the same number on different days, if they _aren't_ you and I have a completely different set of answers.  Was this intended?  What's desired behavior in the case of DST (where a range may have multiple offsets!)?  At minimum your report should explicitly list the offset used, and perhaps be able to switch.  I'd prefer reporting in UTC.

Comment: hey mate. the application stores everything in UTC and then the report is used to demonstrate the time as per timezone. timezone is captured as a parameter of the user running the report

Comment: So, on Monday, the boss runs the report (not including the weekend in his query, nobody works/lower incidents anyways) while he's on vacation in another timezone.  Then, he rings people up to yell at them asking why their Monday and Friday numbers are so low/are working on weekends.  Timezone-shifted management loves this kind of reporting, it's called "Write up those workers who aren't making quota".  People should be using the same set of numbers; either report on UTC, or on the timezone of the "target" (whatever that is).

Comment: Good points. I might look at making the timezone hard-coded. Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty close to what you want.  It uses a subquery to create one row for each of the dates and then summarizes that:

```
SELECT left(DATENAME(dw, thedate), 3) as thedow,, sum(created) as created, sum(resolved) as resolved
FROM ((select DATEADD(mi, @offset, CreatedDateTime) as thedate, 1 as created, 0 as created
       from Incident i
       WHERE DATEADD(mi, @offset, CreatedDateTime) >= @st_datein AND DATEADD(mi, @offset, CreatedDateTime) <= @en_datein
      ) union all
      (select DATEADD(mi, @offset, ResolvedDateTime) as thedate, 1 as created, 0 as created
       from Incident i
       WHERE DATEADD(mi, @offset, CreatedDateTime) >= @st_datein AND DATEADD(mi, @offset, CreatedDateTime) <= @en_datein
      )
     ) i
GROUP BY left(DATENAME(dw, thedate), 3)
ORDER BY left(DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(mi, @offset, thedow)), 3);
```

I left your `order by` in the query.  You might do better to have `order by min(thedate)`.  If that doesn't work, there are other possibilities as well.

Comment: Add a `where` clause if you want a range of dates.  You can add it right before the `group by`.  Somehow, I missed that in the query in your question.

Comment: How are you managing to have two (no, three, there's a typo) columns with the same name in the subquery?  Shouldn't the `WHERE` clause be in the subquery too?  And the date math on the `WHERE` clause could be switched around to make it use an index.  And you're using an inclusive upper bound on a timestamp on what appears to be SQL Server...

Comment: @sequelschmequel . . . I seemed to have only have put in the query I was thinking of.  THis version should be what you are looking for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - two errors - datename function requires 2 argument(s) and incorrect syntax near 'i'

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this:

```
declare @st_date datetime;
declare @en_date datetime;
set @st_date = (@st_datein);
set @en_date = (@en_datein);

declare @offset int;
--set @offset = (@BrowserTimezoneOffset);
set @offset = 600;

with daterange(dt, dow, daynum) as
(select 
    @st_date AS [dt]
    ,LEFT(DATENAME(dw, @st_date),3) AS [dow]
    ,DATEPART(dw,@st_date) as [daynum]
 union all
 select 
    DATEADD(dd, 1, [dt]) as [dt] 
    ,LEFT(DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(dd,1,[dt])),3) as [dow]
    ,DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(dd,1,[dt])) as [daynum]
 from 
    daterange
 where 
    dt <= DATEADD(dd, -1, @en_date)
)
select
    dow
    ,daynum
    ,inc.createdc as createdcount
    ,inr.resolvedclosedc as resolvedclosedcount
from 
    daterange left outer join
(select
    left(DATENAME(dw,DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime)), 3) as createddatetime
    ,count(recid) as createdc
 from 
    Incident
 where 
    DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime) >= @st_date
    and DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime) <= @en_date
 group by  
    left(DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(mi,@offset,CreatedDateTime)), 3)
) as inc
on inc.CreatedDateTime = dow
left outer join
(select
    left(DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(mi,@offset,ResolvedDateTime)), 3) as ResolvedDateTime
    ,count(case when status in ('Resolved', 'Closed') then 1 end) as resolvedclosedc
 from 
    Incident
 where 
    DATEADD(mi,@offset,ResolvedDateTime) >= @st_date 
    and DATEADD(mi,@offset,ResolvedDateTime) <= @en_date 
 group by
    left(DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(mi,@offset,ResolvedDateTime)), 3)
) as inr
on inr.ResolvedDateTime = dow
group by
    dow
    ,daynum
    ,inr.resolvedclosedc
    ,inc.createdc
ORDER BY
    daynum
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```